# My guard always returs null in custom middleware when trying to login

Tags: php, laravel, guard, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I am trying to make multi auth but i just cannot seem to make it work. I am using custom middleware instead of RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware but guard always returns null in my middleware but when i use RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware then it works.
here is my code

Auth.php

```
   'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users'
    ],  
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

user model

```
    public $table = 'users';
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */

 protected $guard = 'user';

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

public function verifyUser() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\VerifyUser');
}
```

}

userLoginController

```
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:user')->except('logout');
}

public function showLoginForm() {
    return view('user.login');
}

protected function guard() {
    return Auth::guard('user');
}

public function login(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8'
    ]);

    if(Auth::guard('user')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        // return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        // if(Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('userdashboard');
        // }
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {   
    echo $user->email_verified_at;
    die();
    // if($user->email_verified_at == null) {
    //     Auth::logout();
    //     return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your email account. We have sent you an email verification code. Please check your email.');
    // }
}

public function logout() {
    session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('userlogin');
}

protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('user/login');
}
```

}

And this is my middleware

```
    public function __construct()
{
    // Auth::shouldUse('user');
}
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if($guard == 'user' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('home')->with('error', 'You do not hava user access');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .... what is returning `null` and how do you know it is returning `null`?

Comment: guard is returning null in my middleware when trying to login. when i dd($guard) in my middleware it shows null

Comment: this middleware isn't a "guest" middleware it is what "auth" is doing ... RedirectIfAuthenticated would redirect authenticated users away, not stop unauthenticated users, you recreated the "auth" middleware instead of "guest", btw

Comment: Yes i am trying to create a custom authentication system myself and i created isUser middleware to only allow authenticated users but the guard returns nulls in that middleware that's the whole problem

Comment: if this middleware is what you have named 'guest' in your Kernel then I don't see a reason it wouldn't be handling the 'guard' parameter that is being passed to it when assigned as `guest:user`

Comment: No i have named the middleware 'user' in kernel

Comment: so where did you assign this middleware? since the only assigned middleware in this code is `guest:user` in the constructor

Comment: i assigned the middleware in my routes likes this... middleware('user')

Comment: and there is no parameter there .... `user` is the middleware, you need to pass a parameter otherwise it is `null` .... this is why you see `guest:user`, `user` is the parameter to the middleware .... `middleware:parameter,paremeter,parameter,...`

Comment: ok what parameter do i need to pass

Comment: pass it what you defined you wanted to pass it, you wrote it

Comment: i want to pass the guard

Comment: so then pass the guard

Comment: ok now the guard is working but when i use Auth::check() to see if the user is logged in it returns false but it still redirects me to dashboard

Comment: how do you know `Auth::check()` is `false`? and `Auth::check()` and `Auth::guard(...)->check()` are potentially different things

Comment: i use this if(Auth;:check()) { echo 'logged in' } else { echo 'not logged in' }

Comment: `Auth::check()` and `Auth::guard($guard)->check()` could be using completely different guards  ... you have to specify the guard ... welcome to multiauth

Comment: but Auth::check() is used to check if a user is authenticated or not

Comment: `Auth::check()` is `Auth::guard('web')->check()` ... `Auth::` without calling `guard` uses the default guard (which is `web` as per your configuration) unless you change it at run time ... you are logging the user into a different guard, the one named `user`, not `web`

Comment: oh ok i get it now.... it's working now thanks mate you really helped me out here

Comment: multi auth is more complicated than people think, i barely ever use it unless I really really need separate tables for different types of users and then they will be segregated on the site

Comment: No it's just that i am new to laravel and trying to understand how it works...That's why i was trying to create multi auth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your Middleware to get a parameter you have to define it with the parameter when you are assigning the middleware:

```
Route::get(...)->middleware('user:user');
```

The first `user` is the middleware's name. After the `:` are the parameters that will be passed to your middleware's `handle` method. So this middleware would end up with `$guard` being `user`.